# How to access the variable passed through res.renderer?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm passing a variable to my template renderer in ExpressJs like so:

**index.js**

```
app.get('/simple_view/', function(req, res, next){
  title='A TITLE';
  res.render('simple', {
          title: title
       });
    });
```

I would like to access the title variable in a JS script on my template page, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined` error.

**simple.pug**

```
script.
   console.log(title);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Getting Started](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for PUG already showcases how to embed variables. You do this by using `#{variable_name}`, e.g. `#{title}` in your case.

Comment: console.log({title}); I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that PUG also requires you to prefix it with `#`.

Comment: I believe {variable_name} can be used to interpolate on HTML but not in JS

Comment: EDIT: it sort of worked! But I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: TITLE is not defined`, and when I pass a value of 'test' I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Comment: So i'm able to sort of access the value of the variable, but why am I getting the undefined error with console.log(#{title});

Comment: I had to use console.log('#{title}') . That fixed it

Comment: Ah right, if it replaces `#{title}` with `A TITLE`, your JS would look like `console.log(A TITLE)` hence the weird `TITLE is not defined` error.